# How to completely remove spaces in copied text in Javascript

Tags: javascript, removing-whitespace

I put a javascript copy button, but this button takes all the spaces in the html. How can I solve this?

JavaScript File:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function(){
    var btntxt = $(this).text();
    
     var copy = $(this).parent().find('.copy').text();

     
     var $temp = $("<input>");
     $("body").append($temp);
     $temp.val(copy).select();
     document.execCommand("copy");
     $temp.remove();
     
    
    
    $('.confirmation').hide().html('<b>' + btntxt + ' </b> Kopyalandı! ').fadeIn(100).delay(1200).fadeOut(200);
   
    $( '.main' ).trigger( "click" );
  });
  
  $('.main div').click(function(){
      var range = document.createRange();
      var selection = window.getSelection();
      range.selectNodeContents(this);
      selection.removeAllRanges();
      selection.addRange(range);
  });
});
```

Html File:

```
<div class="bank-account mb-4 mt-4">
            <button class="button1">
                <span class="copy">
                    <span class="name-text">Text will come here</span>
                </span>
                <button class="button2">
                    <text class="bank-name">Also Text will come here too</text>
                    <i class="far fa-copy" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
            </button>
</div>
```

Also i tried to add remove spaces code but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this line
`var copy = $(this).parent().find('.copy').text();`
with this one
`var copy = $(this).parent().find('.copy').text().replaceAll(" ", "");`

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't fixed. I dont know why.

Still whitespaces are there..

Comment: This line just deletes the first space. Rest of them still there..

Comment: Just use a regExp:  .replace(/ /g, "");
Or the replaceAll method: .replaceAll(" ", "");

Comment: Thanks.. Fully worked.